# Projectile Motion with Wind Effect

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, kinematics, projectile-motion

My first question is about the former question Projectile Motion with Air Resistance and Wind [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007105/projectile-motion-with-air-resistence-and-wind/3077944#3077944), could you suggest a book or article and an example given about wind effect.

My second question is about 3-D projectile motion, I can not find resources about that, I search a linear differential equation related to this and an example given.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find it in every book on classical mechanics. See for example

- R. Douglas Gregory, **Classical Mechanics**,  Cambridge University Press
- J. B. Griffiths, **The Theory of Classical Dynamics**,  Cambridge University Press
- R. Fitzpatrick,  [**Classical Mechanics - An Introductory Course**](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/301/301.pdf)

In all books you can find the 3D projectile motion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.